# Flutter : Dependencies vs dev_dependencies

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]
I want know different between **dependencies** and **dev_dependencies**.

When i put package in **dependencies**/**dev_dependencies** ?

What put package in **dependencies**/**dev_dependencies** make size APK be bigger? ( i not yet try release apk to see different size)

> Because i use **extension** in visual studio code [Pubspec Assist](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeroen-meijer.pubspec-assist), this **extension** auto add **dependencies** to **pubspec.yaml**
>
> Thank's

Comment: Did you read this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108457/whats-the-difference-between-pub-dependencies-and-dev-dependencies

Comment: @ZakariaHossain yea i already read , but i still confused when i put my package to **dependecies/dev_dependecies**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> dependencies

List of plugins that we have to include while deploying your App after completion of your development stage.

> dev_dependencies

List of plugins that you want to try out at the development stage to test the apps at development stage.

For example: In the development stage, we use Mockito and test plugins and SDK to write the test cases and to test the complete behaviour of the app. These kind of plugins and SDK's we include in

> dev_dependencies

So in the release apps, there is no need of adding these plugins or sdk support.

Comment: Not sure why, but if I remove my dev_dependencies from pub spec and then build a release and obfuscated APK everything works where if I don't remove the dev_dependencies, it crashes. Seems like some dev_dependencies do leak to the obfuscated release APK..

I build the APK like using this command:


flutter build apk --debug -t /main.dart --build-number 1 --obfuscate --split-debug-info=debug_info

Comment: @user3193413 same observation. Having to deal with a package that causes problems only in release mode, but I need it in debug mode. I can't fix the issues from it in release mode by moving the package to dev_dependencies. I have to remove the package entirely to fix my problem. dev_dependencies seem to have only meaning, but not enforce it.

Comment: @MartinBraun May I know which package you're using and facing the problem with release mode build?

Comment: @hemandroid https://github.com/ufukhawk/safe_device/issues/33 (I moved to `device_info_plus` to fix it, though)

Answer (score 20):

`dependencies` are packages that are included in your app during compilation while
`dev_dependencies` are packages that you use during developing your app and these are not included in the APK

Comment: Sorry i want little ask , how i know what packages i must put in dev_dependencies/dependencies ? as example i have package `Image picker ,http, splashscreen` between this package ,Which one i must put in dependencies/dev_dependencies ?

Comment: usually it will be documented in the pub.dev examples... but to make it simple... if the app would need the package during runtime, then include it `dependencies`... your examples: `Image picker ,http, splashscreen` are going to be used in the app itself, so you should include them to dependencies

Comment: to give you an example of a package to be placed in dev_dependencies, check out: flutter_launcher_icons... this is a package which enables you to create all the app icons for your app... which you would only need to do during the development of the app...

Comment: But it is mentioned to add splashScreen to dev_dependencies and it is required at runtime right? @digitaljoni

Comment: @Bensal, usually dev_dependencies create files for you to use on your apps... and you only need to run them during development... in the case of flutter_launcher_icons and flutter_native_splash... it will create the images and do some code changes for you... so the created images  and code changes, you will include that to your repo. i hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`dev_dependencies` are only required for development or which are used to build your bundle. Ex: es-lint

`dependencies` should contain libs and framewors your app is built on.Ex: intl

`dev_dependencies` are modules which are only required during development, while `dependencies` are modules which are also required at runtime.

Comment: so if i put all package in `dependecies` make my apk size be bigger than i put all my package in `dev_dependecies` ? or i cant build release apk if my package in `dev_dependecies`?

Comment: You shouldn't put all packages in `dependencies`. But must put all packages in `dependencies` which is required at run time. Suppose: `intl` is a packages for date format, if you put it in `dev_dependencies` - date formatting doesn't work in your app. So you must put `intl` in dependencies. Packages under `dependencies` will increase your apk size.